# background-image on divs aren't showing; the divs are collapsing instead

Tags: html, css, background-image

CSS:

```
body {
  background: url("ninabg.jpg") left top no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% auto;
}

.image {
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-image:url("logo2fix.png");
    position:absolute;
    right:1%;
    bottom:3%;
    height:40%;
    width:35%;
}

.slo {
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-image:url("slo.png");
    position:absolute;
    width:5%;
    bottom:10%;
    right:21%;

}

.eng {
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-image: url("eng.png");
    position:absolute;
    width:5%;
    right:12%;
    bottom:10%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

    <head>

        <!-- META -->
        <title>Nina Rakovec</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Profesionalna igralka" />

        <!-- CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />

    </head>

    <body>

            <div class="image"></div>
            <div class="eng"></div>
            <div class="slo"></div>

    </body>

</html>
```

My website shows the background and only the `<div class="image"></div>`, why aren't the other two `<div class="eng"></div>` and `<div class="slo"></div>` showing up on my website?
I am clueless and have no idea how to fix this, please help me.. also another question, I would like to use the `eng` and `slo` on my website as two pictures which are links if you click on them. But I can't use `div` inside of `a`, how would I do that?

Comment: Add some height to `.slo` & `.eng` and use spans for links but you can also set `background-image` to anchor without divs and spans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The images are not working because `.slo` and `.eng` have no height or content so they, and their background-images, do not appear. Give them both a height:

```
.slo {
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-image:url("slo.png");
    position:absolute;
    width:5%;
    bottom:10%;
    right:21%;
    height:200px;
    display:block
}

.eng {
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-image: url("eng.png");
    position:absolute;
    width:5%;
    right:12%;
    bottom:10%;
    height:200px;
    display:block;
}
```

And for your second problem, you can just use an `<a>` element instead of a `<div>`:

```
<a href="#" class="eng"></a>
<a href="#" class="slo"></a>
```

Or use a `<img>` element to display the images.

## <kbd>[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/J8zhd/6/)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this helped me! I had no idea I had to set height. So I have to simply set height if I want to use it in conjunction with background-image - can I only do this or I am supposed to set the width too? I'm new to CSS and HTML so I have a lot to learn. :)

Comment: @NejcPisk it must have Height and width or content. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, here it is,

instead of wrapping divs or spans in anchor for image links use just anchors e.g.

```
<a href="#" class="eng"></a>
<a href="#" class="slo"></a>
```

---

if you using element with background image you must set both `width` & `height` and `display` property to `block` or `inline-block` if element is not by default block or inline block level element.

```
.slo,
.eng {
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  position:absolute;
  display: block;
  width:5%;
  height:2%; /* You forgot to set height */
  bottom:10%;
}
.slo {
  background-image:url("slo.png");
  right:21%;
}
.eng {
  background-image:url("eng.png");
  right:12%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say you "can't use div inside of a" is that because of a real limitation or just something you read? HTML4 and earlier did not allow anchors to wrap block-level elements like `<div>`, but as of HTML5 (which you are using, based on your DOCTYPE), anchor elements (`<a>`) are allowed to wrap most other elements.

If you truly can't use an anchor element, you can use JavaScript to handle click events on the div instead. (This is not recommended for accessibility reasons, but it should work.)

```
// With jQuery
jQuery('.slo').click(function () {
  window.location = 'new-url';
});

// Without jQuery
document.querySelector('.slo').attachEventListener('click', function () {
  window.location = 'new-url';
}, false);
```

Comment: I know it is allowed in HTML5, but I wanted to make my website compatible with other browsers, especially IE, which is well known for its limitations.
Thanks for your answer, I appreciate it.

Comment: Actually, wrapping anchors around block-level elements has been supported by all browsers for a long time. See: http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/.